# How to reset the sshd config to default in Linux Redhat

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I need the very first version of the ssh config. Located in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Unfortunately  the current ssh config has been changed a few time by other developers and it is hard to understand what is modified.
I wonder is there any way to reset the ssh config on default or if some one has the content of ssh config if you can share it.

Comment: You can find the default version of the config in the installer file for your particular system, just extract it following these [fairly straight forward](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/view-and-extract-packages/) instructions..

Comment: I also recommend either implementing system configuration (Puppet/Chef) or some sort of version control (FSVS).  FSVS is nice because you can use it as a log of what was done on the server via commit messages and you can diff across versions for files in your /etc, or /usr/local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply by moving the file away/deleting it and reinstalling appropriate package.

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/ssh/sshd_config   # to find out what package owns the file
openssh-server
$ mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config{,.old} # backup the modified version
$ yum reinstall openssh-server   # will create the file with default configuration
```

Comment: Thank you @Jakuje. I have done it But it doesn't create a new file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config but then it creates a file called "/etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew". Is this the new file?

Comment: If you didn't (re)move the original file, then yes, the new file is named `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew`

Comment: Thank you then it's fine. Because I have renamed the file to /etc/ssh/sshd_config-bk just in case...